# Is there a way to pass a coupon code as a URL parameter?

Tags: url, session, coupon-codes, parameter

I would like to create URLs which activate a specific coupon.  It could be as simple as passing the coupon code as a URL parameter.   When a coupon is passed, I'd like it to automatically be populated at time of checkout.

**Is there a way to capture a coupon parameter into the session to automatically be applied to the cart?**

Comment: I've used parts of the code of this free module to achieve this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/linksture-discount-coupon-code-link.html

Comment: Copy functionality of creation coupons from magento and put it to your own controller. If you want to use some strange urls - create also your own FRONT controller

Comment: I am currently working for a company that is doing a security analysis on coupon codes, links etc. You should make sure that you encrypt or disguise the coupon code in some way and force the user to login from the link. This is to prevent people who have had their emails hijacked or the like from being able to fraudulently claim coupons.

Comment: There’s an extension called Sticky Coupon that accomplishes just this. ![automated coupon code populated field by using the sticky coupon extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAoy6.png)

Comment: please add more details related to question and how it can help to sort out issue

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143787)

Comment: The most easiest way is to buy this [apply discount extension](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-apply-coupon-via-link.html). Once this extension is installed then you can simply share the link with your customers by adding valid coupon code as shown below. The link will look like this: ***http://{[siteurl}}/applydiscount/?code={[coupon_code}}&redirect_url={[any_url_of_your_site}}***. If the condition is met, the coupon code will be automatically applied to the cart.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do as well. Worked for me in Magento LTS and 1.9.
/checkout/cart/couponPost/coupon_code/MY_COUPON_CODE?return_url=MY_LANDING_PAGE_URL

Answer (score 5):

You can use just the Magento core URL for coupon posting: `http://example.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/coupon_code/MY_COUPON_CODE` You can also add on `?return_url=http...` if you want a specific return url or let it just redirect to the cart by default.

Comment: I'll play with that, and maybe I can use an .htaccess redirect to provide a simple URL that hides the cart details.

Comment: FYI googlers, this is an old answer with no version tags. I tested and this applies to Magento 2 (tested in 2.1.7 CE w/ sample data)

Comment: Mind that this only works if you already have something in your cart.

Comment: For me, Since I have items in cart, this is not working in magento 2.3.0. Any idea?

Comment: @Pribhav In magento 2, they've changed the controller action that it must be a POST request. See here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php
That's why it doesn't work.
You can create a custom controller, and then use that. Basically just copy the content of `CouponPost` into your controller and make your controller implement the `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface`

Comment: The "only works if you already have something in your cart" defeats my purpose for wanting this ability.  My use case is more like an affiliate link so coupons can be automatically associated with their session when they follow a link to the shop.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote something that's free and open source which does exactly what you need and doesn't require items to already be in the cart. You can find it here: https://github.com/crankycyclops/DiscountCodeUrl

It's still pretty new and needs more testing (if you want to help me out, I'd really appreciate it!), but it's working well for me so far.